# How does php mail function know which mail server to use?

Tags: php

I'm working on existing project and I see that we make a call to [mail function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), however I don't see anywhere where we specify smtp server name password etc... My guess it is in some file but where?

Comment: It's probably host-/server-specific, but your SMTP is setup by your host using sendmail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it uses the local OS "mail" command. It uses whatever the operating system is configured to use. If you want to use and SMTP server, name and password, use SwiftMailer.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the behavior of the mail functions in php via the php.ini, and some can be set with `ini_set` (per http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php)

Email configuration options can be found here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php